# Forcing a line break in Inkscape's LaTeX output

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, inkscape

I am using Inkscape, together with its LaTeX output feature, to create a block diagram for a report. I want to link each block in the diagram to a particular section in the report, using a hyperref.

Suppose I create a simple block, containing the text `\hyperref[sect:eg]{Example}`, and I  export this diagram from Inkscape to files called *example.pdf* and *example.pdf_tex*.

[image: Inkscape block with example text]

Then, in my LaTeX file, I write:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{example \label{sect:eg}}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\linewidth}
    \input{example.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This works as expected: the text within the block diagram is clickable and links to the section.

[image]

However, I am now facing a problem where I want a block to contain **two** lines.

[image]

Inserting a linebreak from the Inkscape text editor does not work, nor does adding a linebreak manually ('\\').

The compiler (pdflatex) complains about the following line in the example.pdf_tex file:

`\put(0.44961172,0.29990378){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\hyperref[sect:eg]{Example\\Two}\end{tabular}}}}%`

Are there any clever workarounds for this? I could try messing around with the pdf_tex source code, but ideally a solution from within Inkscape or my main.tex file would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can use the *makecell* package.

[image]

Result with same MWE as in question:

[image: enter code here]